# Getting only one record from parent with multiple child in Linq (Distinct)

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I'm trying to fill in a Typed GridView with a list of products and it's last status.

This first query works OK and returns one record for each Product because of the `Distinct()` clause. But now I need to show the *LAST* Situation and get some data from other tables to display on a *TYPED* `GridView`.

(The **ProductSituationHistory** basically contains **ProductId** and **SituationId**, to keep a track of all status the product have gained...

```
public IQueryable<Product> SelectProducts()
            {
            var query = (from ph in db.ProductSituationHistory
                            join p in db.Products on ph.ProductId equals p.Id
                            join s in db.Situation on ph.SituationId equals s.Id
                            select  p).Distinct();
            return query;
            }
```

So, I created another type class called ProductGridView (I don't like working with anonymous types and the GridView would work better here if it was Strongly Typed) the query is like this:

```
public IQueryable<ProductGridView> SelectProducts()
    {
            var query = (from ph in db.ProductSituationHistory
                            join p in db.Products on ph.ProductId equals p.Id
                            join s in db.Situation on ph.SituationId equals s.Id
                            select new ProductGridView
                            {
                                Id = p.Id,
                                Name = p.Name,
                                Situation = s.Description,
                                Manufacturer = p.Manufacturer.Name

                            }).Distinct();


            return query;
    }
```

The problem is now the `Distinct()` won't work, because, obviously, none of the **ProductGridView** items will be equal (the SituationId changes). How can I get a list of all products while getting only the last record from **ProductSituationHistory** for each of them?

Comment: Why cant you order by date desc and take the first record?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I get a list of all products while getting only the last record from ProductSituationHistory for each of them?

This means we want to start with `Product`, rather than `ProductSituationHistory`, and do a group join.  When you do that you'll have all matching history items as a collection, to which you can, for example, get the last item from.

```
var query = from p in db.Products 
                join ph in db.ProductSituationHistory 
                on p.Id equals ph.ProductId into history
                let lastHistory = history
                    .OrderByDescending(h=>h.Id)
                    .FirstOrDefault()
                join s in db.Situation 
                on lastHistory.SituationId equals s.Id
                select new ProductGridView
                {
                    Id = p.Id,
                    Name = p.Name,
                    Situation = s.Description,
                    Manufacturer = p.Manufacturer.Name,
                };
```

Comment: Thanks, for the solution, Servy. But now I'm getting this issue when running it:    LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'NovoGRH.ENTITIES.ProductSituationHistory Last[ProductSituationHistory ](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1

Comment: I made it work by replacing the Last() with a OrderByDescending(h=>h.Id).FirstOrDefault(). Again, thank you for your help!

Comment: @VitorReis Edited to account for that.

Comment: Can you please help me with this linq query:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38120664/how-to-group-by-on-2-child-entities-and-get-total-of-both-this-child-entities